# NumberFormatter string(from:NSNumber) method has issues with decimal places

Tags: ios, swift, decimal, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber

Here is my code

```
let ns = NumberFormatter.init()
ns.allowsFloats = true
ns.maximumFractionDigits = 18 //This is a variable value
ns.minimumFractionDigits = 18 //This is a variable value
ns.roundingMode = .floor
ns.numberStyle = .decimal
let doubleValueOfDecimal : Double = 12.95699999999998
let numb = NSNumber.init(value: doubleValueOfDecimal)
print(numb)
let string = ns.string(from: numb)
print(string)
```

The following is the output and input 

    `doubleValueOfDecimal = 2.95699999999998
    Output 
    2.95699999999998
    Optional("2.956999999999980000")`

But if I input

```
doubleValueOfDecimal =  12.95699999999998
```

The output is

```
12.95699999999998
Optional("12.957000000000000000")
```

The string conversion rounds up the value.
Can someone explain me how this works?

The string conversion is rounding up the decimal places when I want it to show the exact number.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the declaration, and inferred type if it's not explicit, of `doubleValueOfDecimal`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are falling down the cracks between the expectations of the behaviour of *decimal* numbers and the reality that `Float` and `Double` are *binary floating-point*, that is the fractional part of decimal numbers are sums of 1/10's, 1/100's etc. while for binary numbers it is sums of 1/2's, 1/4's etc. and some values exact in one are inexact in the other and vice-versa.

Change your code to include:

```
let doubleValueOfDecimal : Decimal = Decimal(string:"12.95699999999998")!
let numb = doubleValueOfDecimal as NSDecimalNumber
```

and the output is probably what you expect:

```
12.95699999999998
12.956999999999980000
```

The `Decimal` type is a decimal floating-point value type, `NSDecimalNumber` is a subclass of `NSNumber` which holds a `Decimal` value.

HTH

*(Note: you have to initialise the `Decimal` from a string as using a numeric literal appears to involve the Swift compiler using binary floating point at some point in the process...)*

Comment: A little late, but just realised that this answer had actually helped me solve the problem. Thanks CRD

Answer (score 0):

Use wrapper method of `NSNumber` class. `

> ```
>  print(numb.stringValue)
> ```

```
let ns = NumberFormatter.init()
ns.allowsFloats = true
ns.maximumFractionDigits = 18
ns.minimumFractionDigits = 18
ns.roundingMode = .floor
ns.numberStyle = .decimal
let numb = NSNumber.init(value: doubleValueOfDecimal)
print(numb)
let string = ns.string(from: numb)
print(numb.stringValue)
```

> Below Output for 2.95699999999998 , 12.95699999999998 values.

**Output**

2.95699999999998

2.95699999999998

12.95699999999998

12.95699999999998

Comment: I have used NumberFormatter class for a reason. The maximumFractionDigits and minimumFractionDigits are variables and not constants. So I can't ditch the whole setup for Formatter and directly use the stringValue